# Distributed Text Clustering with Slurm

Tags: artificial-intelligence, text-classification, slurm

I want to build a distributed AI-based text classification solution (e.g. based on distributed k-means) , which should work on my cluster based on Slurm. The solution should cluster the input-documents so that similar documents will be grouped together.

However, I am not sure, which frameworks etc. to use - has someone ideas how I could approach this?

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, the word 'classification' is used for describing a supervised task trained with labels. What you're describing is text clustering, which is unsupervised with no labels.

More precisely, what you're describing is [topic modelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model), a standard task in NLP.

There are various algorithms, the most standard is probably LDA. There are also more recent approaches with DL, for example [Bertopic](https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/index.html).

About distributing with Slurm, there are apparently options as well, for example with [Spark](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/distributed-topic-modelling-using-spark-nlp-and-spark-mllib-lda-6db3f06a4da3) (apparently [Spark can be used on top of Slurm](https://github.com/NIH-HPC/spark-slurm).)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The question I still have is whether it is possible to run BERTopic on several nodes. My goal would be to distribute the input data on several nodes and thus be able to cluster the documents more quickly.

Comment: @rolr I don't know about this, sorry. I searched quickly and there's no obvious answer, so it might not be possible.